# Use node.js to navigate inside a webpage

Tags: node.js

I'm writing an application using Node.js.

One of the functions I want to create is to navigate to a specific URL.

for example:

- navigate inside a website
- taking some informations of the page like (contacts,etc..)

I'm able to take a `URL` but i don't know how to navigate inside it?

some advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to make some sort of crawler, you should have a look at [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) and [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) which is a sort of jquery for node, and HTML parser.

Comment: Yes, i want to create a sort of a crawler.